# Problem with exporting blender materials to unity

Tags: materials, uv, export, shaders, unity

I need to export this model to unity with its materials:
[image]

This model uses a few different materials in different slots:
[image]

The green and grey materials have a random color from a color ramp in each face, which is done with the use of a lightmap pack in UV editing (like in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kBrOzCxOWhM&t=339s&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio).
[image]

Is there any way for me to somehow get these materials working in Unity? I thought that maybe I should somehow bake them but I don't know if it's possible with many materials in one object and if the material itself uses a lightmap pack. I'd really appreciate any help as I really need to have the same look in Unity. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's the first time I will ever be using Unity, but is it possible to do something similar there, as I have done here with each face having a slightly different color? If so, are there any tutorials? I really need this low poly look for the grass especially as otherwise it looks flat, I can't just color it green in Unity.

Comment: I have never used Unity, but I would presume that Unity as do other game engines has it's own shading and material system, thus you would need to use it. Blender (and any other software for that matter) materials will not be compatible. Every shading system is different.

Comment: But does exporting to a game engine preserve faces, so that I can I can do something depending on their shapes etc? I thought that models are imported as one mesh more or less.